# what will be its value at the end of $10$ year?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An equipment cost $x$ unit money, it depriciates in value $15\%$ the first, $13.5\%$ in the next year, $12\%$ in the $3^{rd}$ year and so on.

Could any one tell me what will be its value at the end of $10$ year?
All the percentages applied to the original cost $x$

Thank you for helping.

at the end of one year $= x- x\times {15\over100}$

at the end of second year $= x- x\times { 13.5\over 100}$

at the end of Third year $=x- x\times {12\over 100}$

Comment: Not enough information, there are a lot of different things that could fit your digression pattern of 15, 13.5, 12

Comment: I think decreasing moneys are in arithmetic progression

Comment: Since all the percentages are in terms of the original amount, add up the percentage points to get the total depreciation.

Comment: I think the digression is the previous number minus 3 divided by the year. For example 15... year 2 = 15-(3/2) ... year 3 = 15-(3/2)-(3/3) ... year 4 = 15-(3/2)-(3/3)-(3/4) .. etc

Answer (score 2):

the percentages of depreciation at the end of 1st, 2nd, 3rd years are 15, 13.5, 12, which are in A.P., with a = 15 and d = - 1.5.

Hence, percentage of depreciation in the tenth year = a + (10-1) d = 15 + 9 (-1.5) = 1.5
Also total value depreciated in 10 years = 15 + 13.5 + 12 + ... + 1.5 = 82.5

Hence, the value of equipment at the end of 10 years=100 - 82.5 = 17.5.
now if the cost of value is x then after ten years the residual value is  = .175 x